# TestDisk - getting Structure: Bad when trying to restore partition table

Tags: disk-management, testdisk

Unfortunately the **Disk Management** tool from **Windows 7** corrupted my **partition table** on one of my disk, when I tried to set the **active (boot) flag** on a partition.

The **original structure** of the partitions was something like:

```
/dev/sdc1      100M     System Reserved (Windows 7)
/dev/sdc2      69,9G    Windows 7
/dev/sdc3      146,5G   NTFS data partition
/dev/sdc4      (extended)
  /dev/sdc5    711G     ext4 data partition
  /dev/sdc6    4G       swap partition
```

Apparently the **ext4 data partition** is **missing**. All the other partitions are **mountable/readable**.

**fdisk**'s output:

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l
...
Disk /dev/sdc: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e0e89

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1             2048     206847     204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2  *        206848  146800639  146593792  69,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3        146801970  454002687  307200718 146,5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc4        454002688 1953523711 1499521024   715G  5 Extended
/dev/sdc5       1945137152 1953523711    8386560     4G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Currently I'm trying the restore the partition table with **TestDisk**, running from Ubuntu installed on an other disk.

Apparently the **TestDisk** founds the missing partitions, but when I'm trying to fix the missing partitions, the program shows **Structure: Bad**.

**TestDisk** after running **Analyze**:

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors

 1 P HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800

Bad relative sector.
 2 * HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20  9137 233 56  146593792

Bad relative sector.
 3 P HPFS - NTFS           9138   0  1 28260  91 55  307200718
 4 E extended             28260  91 56 121601  57 56 1499521024
 5 L Linux Swap           121079  47 57 121601  57 56    8386560


>[Quick Search]  [ Backup ]
                            Try to locate partition
```

after running a **Quick Search** the missing partitions are found:

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>* HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800
 P HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20  9137 233 56  146593792
 D HPFS - NTFS           9138   0  1 28260 254 63  307210995
 D Linux                28260 124 25 121079  47 56 1491132416 [Data]
 P Linux Swap           121079  47 57 121601  57 56    8386560 


Structure: Ok.  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
     Enter: to continue
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 104 MB / 100 MiB
```

**P: list files** works as expected on all partitions. The NTFS data partition is shown as D (deleted) for some reason.

The problem is that when I **change the partition characteristics** to match the original structure, it complains that the **structure is bad**

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdc - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 * HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33    12 223 19     204800
 P HPFS - NTFS             12 223 20  9137 233 56  146593792
 P HPFS - NTFS           9138   0  1 28260 254 63  307210995
 L Linux                28260 124 25 121079  47 56 1491132416 [Data]
>L Linux Swap           121079  47 57 121601  57 56    8386560


Structure: Bad. Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition.
Use Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type,
     Enter: to continue
SWAP2 version 1, pagesize=4096, 4293 MB / 4095 MiB
```

and I cant figure out what exactly the problem is.

An idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You've added the Linux partition as a Logical partition.
You should have an extended partition in which you have the Linux partition and the swap.